# Aligning labels in geom_text_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

## The problem

I am trying to replicate the text alignment and even spacing as in `hjust = 0` panel from the ggrepel examples:
[image]

## My plot

The difficulty is that I have concatenated multiple string into single labels so that the line segments don't make the plot look too messy. These larger labels don't seem to be playing well with one another:
[image]

## The data

```
nest_data <- structure(list(rate = c(27, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 
16, 15, 10, 8, 7.7, 5), country_groups = c("Hungary", "Denmark\n Norway\n Sweden", 
"Finland\n Greece\n Iceland", "Ireland\n Poland\n Portugal", 
"Italy\n Slovenia", "Belgium\n Czech Republic\n Latvia\n Lithuania\n Netherlands\n Spain", 
"Austria\n Estonia\n France\n Slovak Republic\n United Kingdom", 
"Chile\n Germany", "Turkey", "Israel\n Luxembourg", "Mexico", 
"New Zealand", "Australia\n Korea", "Japan", "Switzerland", "Canada"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

## My attempt

```
(nest_data_vat_plot <- ggplot(nest_data, aes(y = rate, x = 1, label = country_groups)) +
    geom_point(color = "red") +
    theme(
      axis.line.x  = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      plot.title   = element_text(hjust = 0),
      panel.background = element_blank()
    ) +
    xlim(1, 1.1) +
    geom_text_repel(
      nudge_x      = 0.035,
      direction    = "y",
      hjust        = 0
    ) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(2.5, 30, 2.5)) + 
    labs(
      title = "Consumption tax rates",
      caption = "Source: OECD Tax Stats \n2019 data presented \nRef: oecd_vat_gst_rates.R",
      x = "",
      y = ""
    ))
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure whether I understand your problem, but you might want to try to remove the spaces after `\n` when pasting the labels, i.e. `Denmark\nNorway\nSweden` instead of `Denmark\n Norway\n Sweden`

Comment: I've tried and it resulted in the text within the labels overlapping